# When will LD_PRELOAD be ignored

Tags: c, linux

I'm trying to use LD_PRELOAD to wrap some functions in a system, I first exported the environment variable `LD_PRELOAD` to point to my `.so` file, then I run the system, I always get `ERROR: ld.so: object '/full/path/to/wrap.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded: ignored.` So I tried to understand LD_PRELOAD on the man page:

> A list of additional, user-specified, ELF shared libraries to be loaded before all others. The items of the list can be separated by spaces or colons. This can be used to selectively override functions in other shared libraries. The libraries are searched for using the rules given under DESCRIPTION. For set-user-ID/set-group-ID ELF binaries, preload pathnames containing slashes are ignored, and libraries in the standard search directories are loaded only if the set-user-ID permission bit is enabled on the library file.

I don't 100% understand the above text, first, it says

> For set-user-ID/set-group-ID ELF binaries, preload pathnames containing slashes are ignored

If I can't use slashes, how can I set the full path of LA_PRELOAD?

second, it says

> and libraries in the standard search directories are loaded only if...

what is the standard search directories?

My final question is understanding when will LD_PRELOAD be ignored? Thank you for your help.

**Edit:**

**When I exported the LD_PRELOAD to a shared library in `/usr/lib/` like this: `export LD_PRELOAD=shared-lib.so`, I got rid of the above error, but I have no root privileges, so I'm not able to put any files under `/usr/lib/`, any suggestions about this? I think if I can manage to export the LD_PRELOAD without any slashes, it should work, but unless the shared library file is in `/usr/lib/`, LD_PRELOAD requires the full path.**

Comment: `LD_PRELOAD` follows the standard library search path. i.e. you can specify relative paths to e.g. `/usr/lib`, but not an absolute path. This only applies to setuid/setgid binaries, though. Note that this behaviour is highly system dependent and the latter only applies for Linux. On other systems `LD_PRELOAD` is unset for setuid/setgid.

Comment: Are you running a program which has the set-user-ID or set-group-ID flag?

Comment: @immibis this is also another question, how can I identify if a binary is `set-user-ID`?

Comment: @user4016367 Surprisingly, someone just posted this at http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/192588/how-to-identify-if-a-binary-file-is-set-user-id (was that you?)

Comment: Also, most binaries are *not* set-user-ID, which means you can use slashes.

Comment: @immibis Yes, it was me, I've got the answer.

Answer (score 5):

You may want to export `LD_DEBUG=files` to get a bit of insight of what's going on, although the output will be quite verbose and it may take you a while to find relevant lines.

EDIT: since that didn't help, you may want to try other `LD_DEBUG` options:

```
libs        display library search paths
reloc       display relocation processing
files       display progress for input file
symbols     display symbol table processing
bindings    display information about symbol binding
versions    display version dependencies
all         all previous options combined
statistics  display relocation statistics
unused      determined unused DSOs
help        display this help message and exit
```

`all` looks like an overkill, but maybe `libs` or `symbols` will show something useful.

Comment: Hi, it just prints `ERROR: ld.so: object '/full/path/to/wrap.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded: ignored`, how to know why it's ignored.

Comment: Another cause of the same message, the one that just tripped me: the executable was (to my surprise) an i386 one and the shared library was an amd64 one, ie 32 bit versus 64 bit.  The system in question supports both but not mix-and-match in one process.  "Why does LD_DEBUG=all keep mentioning i386?" set me straight - thanks.

Answer (score 3):

This means two things:

1. Either '/full/path/to/wrap.so' is not a shared library (check with `file '/full/path/to/wrap.so'`),
2. Or '/full/path/to/wrap.so' is missing (itself) a shared library (check that with `ldd '/full/path/to/wrap.so'`)

If the above is not usefull, then try a very low level tool:

```
$ strace /path/to/your/exe/which/load/wrap.so 2>&1 | grep '/full/path/to/wrap.so'
```

If you want to get some context, try using `-3` in grep (or any larger number):

```
$ strace /path/to/your/exe/which/load/wrap.so 2>&1 | grep -3 '/full/path/to/wrap.so'
```

Comment: I created wrap.so, I think it's something relevant to the user id.

Comment: @user4016367 What is the output of the 2 commands(`file` and `ldd` ) that malat asked about ?

Comment: @nos No1: `wrap.so: ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, not stripped`, No 2: `linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xffffe000)
 libdl.so.2 => /lib/libdl.so.2 (0xf7713000)
 libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0xf75a6000)
 /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xf7780000)
`

Comment: @user4016367 why are you tagging `c++`, your shared lib is not using `libstdc++.so.6` ?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what malat said, it may be at least two other reasons:

1. Your preload library is not accessible. It is probably not the case if you have access to only one non-root user on your system.
2. You have the `noexec` flag set on the filesystem where your preload library is placed.

To check the first case, log in as the user from which you are trying to run your program and run `nm /path/to/preload/library.so` -- you have to get some symbols printed to console.

On the second case, the man page for `mmap` says about possible errors:

> EPERM  The prot argument asks for PROT_EXEC but the mapped area belongs to a file on a filesystem that was mounted no-exec.

To check this you may copy `/bin/ls` to the same directory as your preload library and try to run it. If `ls -l ./ls` shows x flags, but trying to execute `./ls` says `Permission denied`, then you probably have `noexec` set. Of course, you may check the output of `mount` command for the presence of `noexec`, but you may need to take into account nested mounts of pseudo filesystems such as ~/Private on some Ubuntu installations.